# How to extend shopware.api.customergroup

Tags: shopware

I am trying to extend Shopware v5.4.6's \Shopware\Components\Api\Resource\CustomerGroup by adding attributes to it yet it is not showing in the API response.

I have tried to repurpose extending the Customer API resource example but it did not work.

"SwagExtendCustomerGroupResource\Components\Api\Resource\CustomerGroup.php"

```php
class CustomerGroup extends \Shopware\Components\Api\Resource\CustomerGroup
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getOne($id)
    {
        $result               = parent::getOne($id);
        $result ['attribute'] = $result->getAttribute();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

"SwagExtendCustomerGroupResource\Resources\services.xml"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="swag_extend_customer_group_resource.customer_group_resource"
                 class="SwagExtendCustomerGroupResource\Components\Api\Resource\CustomerGroup"
                 decorates="shopware.api.customergroup"
                 public="false"
                 shared="false">
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

I was expecting to see "attribute" property yet it is not showing

Comment: The API endpoint of customer groups does not include attributes as you can see in the [documentation](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/models/#customer-group) of the API models or directly on [github](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.6/engine/Shopware/Components/Api/Resource/CustomerGroup.php#L50)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the original `getOne` method, the query builder does not select the attributes of the customer group.

So if you want to select the attributes, you need to overwrite this method completely:

```php
public function getOne($id)
{
   $this->checkPrivilege('read');

   if (empty($id)) {
      throw new ApiException\ParameterMissingException('id');
   }

   $builder = $this->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('customerGroup')
       ->select('customerGroup', 'd', 'attr') // <-- add select
       ->leftJoin('customerGroup.discounts', 'd')
       ->leftJoin('customerGroup.attribute', 'attr') // <-- join attributes
       ->where('customerGroup.id = :id')
       ->setParameter(':id', $id);

   $query = $builder->getQuery();
   $query->setHydrationMode($this->getResultMode());

   /** @var \Shopware\Models\Customer\Group $category */
   $result = $query->getOneOrNullResult($this->getResultMode());

   if (!$result) {
      throw new ApiException\NotFoundException(sprintf('CustomerGroup by id %d not found', $id));
   }

   return $result;
}
```

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann